# Upgrade Entity Framework to 6.1 - index already exists errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I just upgraded a project with a code-first model from Entity Framework 6.0.2 to 6.1.0.

After the upgrade, `context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(true)` returns false, so EF thinks the database is no longer compatible with the model. I haven't changed anything else, just upgraded EF.

I ran `Add-Migration` to see what would happen, and EF created a big migration that seems to create an index on every foreign key property on every table:

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateIndex("dbo.ActivityStreams", "UserId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Users", "OfficeId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Offices", "ParentId");
        CreateIndex("dbo.Rosters", "UserId");
        ...and many more similar lines...
```

I guess this is related to the new index features in EF 6.1? A bit strange, but OK.

When I `Update-Database` to apply the new migration, there are errors that the indexes already exist. Looking in the database and at previous migrations, almost all the indexes do indeed already exist.

What have I done wrong here? Is there a procedure for upgrading EF?

Comment: Have you created any indices by yourself?

Comment: No, all the existing indexes were created by EF migrations.

Comment: Exactly the same scenario here. A bug indeed -(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the exact same issue. I fixed it by recreating the Indexes.

I've accomplished this by copy pasting the DropIndexes from the Down method in the migration into the Up method. 
So effectively first deleting the indexes and then recreating them.
No idea why this is necessary but it fixed the problem.

Comment: Then this sounds like a bug in EF 6.1. Have you reported it?

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in other answers, this is due to an Entity Framework bug. The accepted answer of copying the `DropIndex` code into the `Up` method causes unnecessary work on the database. Instead, I would suggest that the correct course of action is to delete the contents of both the `Up` and `Down` methods as these indexes already exist and do not need to be removed.

Comment: +1: this will create an empty dummy task that will only write the hash of the model schema to the migration history as EF6.1 sees it.

Answer (score 1):

Re: Your Foreign Keys being created, I found the following info at the following link:

http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2014/02/15/ef-6-1-creating-indexes-with-indexattribute/  states the following:

The ForeignKeyIndexConvention Code First convention causes indexes to be created for the columns of any foreign key in the model unless these columns already have an index specified using IndexAttribute. If you don’t want indexes for your FKs you can remove this convention:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ForeignKeyIndexConvention>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This fixed my issue.  We have been iterating on a system  and creating our own indexes, since EF had limited functionality for it.  We used nuget and updated all packages.  Once we did, because of new ef, our migration plan failed to work.  This option above, brought everything back to normal!   :)

Answer (score 1):

In **EF core 6**

1- add **CreateIndexIfNotExists** extension method

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.Builders;

public static OperationBuilder<SqlOperation> CreateIndexIfNotExists(
        this MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder,
        string name,
        string table,
        string column)
    {
        return migrationBuilder.Sql(@$"IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = '{name}')
                        BEGIN
                            CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [{name}] ON [dbo].[{table}]
                            (
                            [{column}] ASC
                            ) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
                        END
        ");
    }
```

2- change your up migration method to use CreateIndexIfNotExists

```
public partial class Add_Index_TableName_ColumnName : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    { 
        migrationBuilder.CreateIndexIfNotExists(
            name: "IX_TableName_ColumName",
            table: "TableName",
            column: "ColumName");
    }
```

3- do the similar code for your down method in your migration

Comment: Thanks! I added a `unique` parameter (with as default false) to the method so that you can also use it with the unique constraint. The CREATE statement is then: `CREATE {(unique ? "UNIQUE" : "")} NONCLUSTERED INDEX`...